# Python Looping with etree

Tags: python, xml, loops

I'm sure many of you have seen the inundation of minidom questions I've had as of late. This weekend, I finally gave up and moved to etree, and have one simple question: How should I be looping this to give the output in the following format:

Name Class_Name members color #field y #field z

XML example (there are many different types of Class_Name):

```
<network_objects>
<network_object>
<Name>Test_Group_A</Name>
<Class_Name>network_object_group</Class_Name>
<members>
  <reference>
    <Name>Host1</Name>
    <Table>network_objects</Table>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <Name>Host2</Name>
    <Table>network_objects</Table>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <Name>Host3</Name>
    <Table>network_objects</Table>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <Name>Host4</Name>
    <Table>network_objects</Table>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <Name>Host5</Name>
    <Table>network_objects</Table>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <Name>Host6</Name>
    <Table>network_objects</Table>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <Name>Host7</Name>
    <Table>network_objects</Table>
  </reference>
</members>
<color><![CDATA[deep pink]]></color>
<comments><![CDATA[no comment]]></comments>
<group_convention_query><![CDATA[]]></group_convention_query>
<group_sort_type>3</group_sort_type>
<is_convention_on>false</is_convention_on>
<member_class><![CDATA[network_object]]></member_class>
<members_query><![CDATA[]]></members_query>
<type><![CDATA[group]]></type>
  </network_object>
 </network_objects>
```

The following code gives me one iteration of each name (what I want):

```
for Name in tree.iterfind('network_object/Name'):
    print (Name.text)
```

However, if I do a for loop within the for loop, I get an output of all names, with all variations of Class_Name (versus what it is in reality). For instance:

```
for Name in tree.iterfind('network_object/Name'):
    for Class_name in tree.iterfind('network_object/Class_Name'):
          print (Name.text,Class_name.text)

DB_Servers host_plain
DB_Servers network_object_group
DB_Servers dynamic_object
```

etc etc, I'm sure you get the idea.

How would I go about collecting all of the data I need, and then placing each object with it's relevant details, on it's own line?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post usable XML in examples.

Comment: Fixed - added real XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the `<Name>` and the `<Class_Name>` are children of the `<network_object>`. So you could use `iterfind` to find all the `<network_objects>`, and then use `find` to find the single `<Name>` and `<Class_Name>` child elements:

---

For example, with this setup:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

content='''<network_objects>
<network_object>
<Name>Test_Group_A</Name>
<Class_Name>network_object_group</Class_Name>
<members>
  <reference>
    <Name>Host1</Name>
    <Table>network_objects</Table>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <Name>Host2</Name>
    <Table>network_objects</Table>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <Name>Host3</Name>
    <Table>network_objects</Table>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <Name>Host4</Name>
    <Table>network_objects</Table>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <Name>Host5</Name>
    <Table>network_objects</Table>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <Name>Host6</Name>
    <Table>network_objects</Table>
  </reference>
</members>
</network_object>
</network_objects>  
'''
```

The code

```
root = ET.fromstring(content)
for network in root.iterfind('network_object'):
    name = network.find('Name')
    class_name = network.find('Class_Name')
    print (name.text,class_name.text)
    for subname in network.iterfind('members/reference/Name'):
        print(subname.text)
```

yields

```
('Test_Group_A', 'network_object_group')
Host1
Host2
Host3
Host4
Host5
Host6
```

Comment: Great, and how would you suggest handling embedded objects such as network_object/members/reference/Name?

Comment: Use `for subname in network.iterfind('members/reference/Name')`. I've edited the code above to show what I mean.

Comment: Awesome - two questions: 1) Is there a way to have those group member hosts output on the same line, and - removed #2...typos

Comment: If you store them in a list instead of printing, you can do all sorts of magic.`', '.join(the_list)` gives you them comma separated.

Comment: Thanks for the tips ferrix - unutbu - How am I supposed to define 'content' in the first line? I'm getting 'content' is not defined >.<

Comment: I swear I'll give you that checkmark if you help define my 'content' :D

Comment: content='''<network_objects>''' does it obviously, but I'm getting whacky errors :\

Comment: `content` is defined above in the "setup". If you have the XML in a file, then you could use `tree = ET.parse(filename)` instead.